# AMFPHP how to access classes outside amfphp

Tags: php, actionscript-3, class, amfphp

My class log is in directory:

```
www/includes/classes/log.php
```

with a method

```
public function add($type){
    if($type!=''){
        $this->addRow($type);
    }
}
```

AmfPHP class abc exist in directory

```
www/game/r1/amfphp-file/serv/xyz.php
```

it has a function which calls above method like this

```
$log = new log();
$log->add('gameStart');
```

The problem comes in my flash game AS3:
    NetConnection.Call.BadVersion

when I remove these lines game runs fine (without any trouble):

```
//$log = new log();
//$log->add('gameStart');
```

what I have figured out that my external class is not accessible or ...

Comment: Can you add a little bit more code to show more context?  For example, how are you including your `log` class in `xyz` class? Also, where exactly are those two lines of code found within `xyz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bad version" means that you probably have some PHP error message that is being output. This corrupts your return data.

See www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/ 
especially
What is “NetConnection.Call.BadVersion”?